# index.html# instead of index.html

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying out Angular templates by inserting

```
<ng-include src=="'menu.html'"></ng-inlude>
```

directive between header and footer of an "index.html" file. The webpage shows properly in firefox but chrome doesn't show the template. It loads a file named "index.html#" that doesn't exist in my app folder. I have absolutely no idea what happens here and found no similar case in web searches. Thanks for your help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Ristorante Con Fusion</title>    

<!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
<link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"       rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/"><img src="images/logo.png" height=30 width=41></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#/">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/aboutus">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/menu">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                     Menu</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#/contactus">
                 <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>         

<header class="jumbotron">

    <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action   -->

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-header">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                <h1>Ristorante con Fusion</h1>
                <p style="padding:40px;"></p>
                <p>We take inspiration from the World's best cuisines, and create
                 a unique fusion experience. Our lipsmacking creations will 
                 tickle your culinary senses!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
            <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
            <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<ng-include src="'dishdetail.html'"></ng-include>

<footer class="row-footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">             
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                <h5>Links</h5>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5">
                <h5>Our Address</h5>
                <address>
                  121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
                  Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
                  HONG KONG<br>
                  <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>: +852 1234 5678<br>
                  <i class="fa fa-fax"></i>: +852 8765 4321<br>
                  <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>: 
                     <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">
                     confusion@food.net</a>
                </address>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                <div class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding: 40px 10px;">
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-google-plus" href="http://google.com/+"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id="><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-linkedin" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter" href="http://twitter.com/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-youtube" href="http://youtube.com/"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="mailto:"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <p style="padding:10px;"></p>
                <p align=center>© Copyright 2015 Ristorante Con Fusion</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

<!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

</body>

</html>
```

menu.html:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="MenuController">
        <div class="col-xs-12">

            <button ng-click="toggleDetails()" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary pull-right"                    
                type="button">{{showDetails ? 'Hide Details':'Show Details'}}
            </button> 

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation"
                    ng-class="{active:isSelected(1)}">
                <a ng-click="select(1)"
                 aria-controls="all menu"
                 role="tab">The Menu</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"
                    ng-class="{active:isSelected(2)}">
                <a ng-click="select(2)"
                 aria-controls="appetizers"
                 role="tab">Appetizers</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"
                    ng-class="{active:isSelected(3)}">
                <a ng-click="select(3)"
                 aria-controls="mains"
                 role="tab">Mains</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"
                    ng-class="{active:isSelected(4)}">
                <a ng-click="select(4)"
                 aria-controls="desserts"
                 role="tab">Desserts</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <ul class="media-list tab-pane fade in active">
                    <li class="media" ng-repeat="dish in dishes | filter:filtText">
                        <div class="media-left media-middle">
                            <a href="#">
                            <img class="media-object img-thumbnail"
                             ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="{{dish.name}}">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                             <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                             <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span></h2>
                            <p ng-show="showDetails">{{dish.description}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show more of your `index.html` file?

Comment: You have to define src attr for ng-include when you attach it as tag

Comment: Thanks Andriy. It's edited but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that angular is appending a # to the end of url strings.  This was an older workaround used to prevent non-html5 browsers from sending http requests and reloading the entire page content on single page apps.

But it would be helpful to see your index.html as well as your menu.html files.

Comment: `menu.html` has quotes around it because it is an interpolated value. Without the quotes angular will try to resolve `$scope.menu.html` whereas with quotes it just takes the string value.

Comment: Got it.  That makes sense.

Comment: ng-include expects a string as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to call it as tag you have to add src value**

```
<ng-include src="'menu.html'"></ng-include>
```

Also, you can add ng-include as attribute:

```
<div ng-include="'menu.html'"></div>
```

**Good Luck !**

Comment: Thanks Andriy, that's right of course. Unfortunately, that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is html5mode problem. use `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` in angular config.

Comment: At the beginning of the controllers.js file?

Comment: I tried 'angular.module('confusionApp')
    
        .config(function($locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        });' which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Chrome etc. don't show local files. You have to either check them with a simple webserver or add --allow-file-access-from-files to the google.exe command. Firefox gives access to local files by default. That's why the templates showed in Firefox.